# I am trying to implement an image upload feature on my Django project but no file is being created. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload, django-views

I have a profile page with a default profile picture and a 'Change' button beside it which will trigger a modal upon being clicked. In this modal, the image upload button (for choosing the image) will appear along with a submit button. I have created a separate view for handling the image upload. I do not know why a file is not being created after upload. No error message is being given by Django. I suspect it has something to do with settings.py configuration or the action part of my modal  field.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import KeyForm, Weekly_Item_Form, Daily_Item_Form, ProfileForm
from .models import Key, Weekly_Item, Daily_Item, Profile


def profile_view(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    mainprofile = profiles.last()
    if profiles:
        form = ProfileForm()
        context = {
            'page_title':"Profile", 
            'mainprofile':mainprofile,
            'form': form
        }
    else:
        context = {'page_title':"Profile"}
    return render(request, "bujo/profile.html", context)


def update_image(request, pk):
    mainprofile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ProfileForm(instance=mainprofile)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=mainprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    return redirect('profile')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('profile/', app_views.profile_view, name='profile'),
    path('update_image/<str:pk>', app_views.update_image, name='update_image'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

profile.html

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'update_image' mainprofile.pk %}"> {% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form.image }}
             <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary"" value='Change profile picture' />
             </form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'image', 'nickname', 'bio']
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
```

Comment: please add your `forms.py`

Comment: @SMoenig I have added it as requested

Comment: I have also been able to upload a photo via the admin page and it has copied the image file in /media/images.

Comment: have you set the `upload_to`-parameter on the model-field? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: Yes I have. Tested it via the admin page and it works there but not through a form upload.

Comment: Your form also has other fields than just image. You don't render them so your form is not considered valid when you submit it. It is not very obvious because you simply redirect in all cases when the form is submitted.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I see. What approach should I take? As it is, I need to give the user the option to upload an image independently of the other form fields.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Would creating a separate form for the image suffice?

Comment: @M.Fil yes. Check my answer. Also the line `mainprofile = profiles.last()` is very weird. Is it just a placeholder for now?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for pointing that out. I will reduce the redundancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form has fields other than image also. You don't render them in the template but the form class expects them, so when the form is submitted it is considered to be not valid. If you want to update only the image create another form class which has only the image field.

In your `forms.py` add another form class:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class ProfileImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

In your views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import KeyForm, Weekly_Item_Form, Daily_Item_Form, ProfileForm, ProfileImageForm
from .models import Key, Weekly_Item, Daily_Item, Profile


def profile_view(request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    mainprofile = profiles.last() # This line feels weird! You always make the form for the last profile only.
    if profiles:
        form = ProfileImageForm()
        context = {
            'page_title':"Profile", 
            'mainprofile':mainprofile,
            'form': form
        }
    else:
        context = {'page_title':"Profile"}
    return render(request, "bujo/profile.html", context)


def update_image(request, pk):
    mainprofile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ProfileImageForm(instance=mainprofile)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=mainprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    return redirect('profile')
```